# Route account creation in Razor pay

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, payment-gateway, razorpay

Is there a way to create Account from API for route purpose in Razorpay?

I cannot find any API for this.
I got this but there is nothing helpful :

> https://razorpay.com/docs/api/

Please help
Thank you